# Android - Sharing with Intent using the last action

Tags: android, android-intent

When using Intent for sharing (`Intent.ACTION_SEND`), how can I remember the last app used for sharing and add a shortcut for that app?

In my app, if I have just shared my article using gmail, can I add a shortcut "sharing with gmail" so that I could directly share with gmail without having to select an application?

Thank in advance!

Comment: [ShareActionProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ShareActionProvider.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no listener to detect which app you choose in a default intent chooser.
Therefore, you have to create a dialog which contains all intents for `ACTION_SEND` by yourself.

You can get a intent list for `ACTION_SEND` by the following code.

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
PackageManager pm = v.getContext().getPackageManager();
List<ResolveInfo> activityList = pm.queryIntentActivities(shareIntent, 0);
```

Then, use the list to build a dialog, add listener for each intent.
After user tap one of them, save its' package name. You can retrieve the package name by `ResolveInfo.activityInfo.name`.

Next, you can use the package name to filter `ACTION_SEND`, only firing the filtered app.
Here is a snippet for launching Twitter app.

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
PackageManager pm = v.getContext().getPackageManager();
List<ResolveInfo> activityList = pm.queryIntentActivities(shareIntent, 0);
for (final ResolveInfo app : activityList) {  
    if ("com.twitter.android.PostActivity".equals(app.activityInfo.name)) {
        final ActivityInfo activity = app.activityInfo;
        final ComponentName name = new ComponentName(activity.applicationInfo.packageName,activity.name);
        shareIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
        shareIntent.setComponent(name);
        v.getContext().startActivity(shareIntent);
        break;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!